# How to convert a PY to EXE using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

So this is what I tried.  I found out the hard way that "PIP INSTALL" does not work for me.  Not sure if it is a Windows thing or I need less ID10T on my keyboard.  After much weeping and gnashing of teeth, the PATH to Python is added to the Window thingy.  When you live in Florida, googling "Python Path" shows the Everglades, so this is easier said than done.  Even after the path is added, "PIP" STILL does NOT work.
But this command DOES work for PIP Install

```
python -m pip install pyinstaller
```

Not sure why, but it works with "PYTHON -M" prefix, so I go with it.  So I see a bunch of responses indicating that Pyinstaller is installed.  Here are a few snippets:

> Successfully built pyinstaller
> Successfully installed altgraph-0.17 future-0.18.2 pefile-2021.5.24 pyinstaller-4.3
> pyinstaller-hooks-contrib-2021.1 pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0

Where?  No clue.  I ran it in the folder of my PY file that I want to convert.  No indication that it is there.  Now, when I try to run PYINSTALLER using the same trick as PIP, I hit the next wall.

> python -m pyinstaller --onefile main.py
> No module named pyinstaller

Any direction to get to the next step is appreciated.  Do I need to add another path for "PIP Installed items"??

UPDATE:  I am not sure why a space makes such a big difference, but here is a summary of what finally worked

> A>Pyinstaller --onefile main.py
> B>python -m Pyinstaller --onefile main.py
> C> python -m PyInstaller --onefile main.py

A and B did NOT work.  C did work.  C is B with an added space at the beginning.  Yeah...baffles me too.

Comment: Try this: python -m PyInstaller --onefile main.py

Comment: You have to add the main folder path and the scripts folder path

Comment: After installation, your *run* it with `pyinstaller yourprogram.py` from the command-line. See the [QuickStart](https://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: @iagerogiannis Inadvertently - That worked.  Not because the "P" was capitalized.  I accidentally copied the space before " python" and that worked.  No extra space with capital P gives the same response that I saw before.

Comment: @TL: `C` also put a space between `--onefile` and `main.py`, which is almost certainly the important part; `B` passed `--onefilemain.py`, which would be seen as a single switch, not a switch followed by the associated file name. Also, `B` spelled it `Pyinstaller` (lower case `i`), while `C` spelled it `PyInstaller` (capital `I`). Capitalization matters in module names.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger I corrected my code to match.  Originally, I did have a space between --ONEFILE and MAIN.PY in my command prompt.  GOOD CATCH on the Capital "I".  I didn't catch that.  That makes more sense now!!

Comment: @TL the update is still wrong. It is not the extra space that makes the difference between `B` and `C`, but the capital "I".

Comment: Just install auto-py-to-exe as well and use that